# Limit of one integral, how to use L'Hospital's rule

Tags: limits

I came across one problem, $$\lim_{x\to \overline{x}} \frac{\int_{x}^{\overline{x}}w(t)f(t)\,dt}{\int_{x}^{\overline{x}}w(t)g(t)\,dt}.$$ I know that $w(\overline{x})=0$ and $g(\overline{x})>0$ and $f(x)\neq 0$. If I use L'Hospital's rule, the limit would be $\frac{w(\overline{x})f(\overline{x})}{w(\overline{x})g(\overline{x})}$. But $w(\overline{x})=0$! So how to calculate this limit ?

Comment: There are many missing hypotheses. Please include them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

for $f(x)>0$ and $ g(\overline{x})\ne 0$
$$
\lim_{x \to \overline {x}}\frac{w(x)f(x)}{w(x)g(x)}=\lim_{x \to \overline {x}}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \qquad (1)
$$

---

$$\lim_{x\to \overline{x}} \frac{\int_{x}^{\overline{x}}w(t)f(t)\,dt}{\int_{x}^{\overline{x}}w(t)g(t)\,dt}=
\lim_{x\to \overline{x}} \frac{-\int^{x}_{\overline{x}}w(t)f(t)\,dt}{-\int^{x}_{\overline{x}}w(t)g(t)\,dt}
$$

Using L'Hopital and the fundamental theorem this is the limit $(1)$.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the original limit problem is equal to $\lim_{x \to \overline{x}} \frac{w(x)f(x)}{w(x)g(x)}=\lim_{x \to \overline{x}} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$  ?

Comment: I added to my answer. I hope it's useful :)

Comment: Thank you. Besides $w(\overline{x})=0$, $w(x)=0$ for some $x<\overline{x}$. can I still cancel out $w(x)$ in $\lim_{x \to \overline{x}}\frac{-w(x)f(x)}{-w(x)g(x)}$?

Comment: Yes you can. It is similar to $lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$

Comment: Is $\lim_{x \to \overline{x}} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f(\overline{x})}{g(\overline{x})}$ right when f(x) and g(x) are continuous?

Answer (score 1):

By the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus),
$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_x^{\bar x} h(t) \, dt = -h(x).$$

Combine this with [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).

---

**EDIT**

The limit is of the form $[\frac00]$, so [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) can be used:
$$L := \lim_{x\to\bar x} \frac{\int_{x}^{\bar x} w(t) f(t) \, dt}{\int_{x}^{\bar x} w(t) g(t) \, dt}
= \lim_{x\to\bar x} \frac{\frac{d}{dx} \int_{x}^{\bar x} w(t) f(t) \, dt}{\frac{d}{dx} \int_{x}^{\bar x} w(t) g(t) \, dt}.$$

Now, by the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus),
$\frac{d}{dx} \int_x^{\bar x} h(t) \, dt = -h(x),$
so
$$L = \lim_{x\to\bar x} \frac{- w(x) f(x)}{- w(x) g(x)} = \lim_{x\to\bar x} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}.$$

Comment: could you please give more details ? I cannot catch your idea. Thank you.

Comment: @congmingniao: The post have been edited.

Comment: Thank you. Besides $w(\overline{x})=0$, $w(x)=0$ for some $x<\overline{x}$. can I still cancel out $w(x)$ in $\lim_{x \to \overline{x}}\frac{-w(x)f(x)}{-w(x)g(x)}$ ?

Comment: As long as you take $x \neq \bar x$ during taking the limit.

Comment: Is $\lim_{x \to \overline{x}} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f(\overline{x})}{g(\overline{x})}$ right when f(x) and g(x) are continuous?

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $\bar x$ then it's certainly true. If they are not continuous then we'll have to stay with the left side.